# Connect Spring Boot 2.4.x to neo4j-3.4.x

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I'm trying to connect a `Spring Boot 2.4.6` service to a `Neo4j 3.4.18-enterprise` server, but I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: The server does not support any of the protocol versions supported by this driver. Ensure that you are using driver and server versions that are compatible with one another.
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:143)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.run(InternalSession.java:69)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalSession.run(InternalSession.java:51)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:37)
at org.neo4j.driver.internal.AbstractQueryRunner.run(AbstractQueryRunner.java:43)
... 99 more
```

Reading this [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/wiki/Versions#all-supported-versions) I'm assuming (or rather I'm hoping) there should be a way to make `Spring Boot 2.4.x` work with `Neo4j 3.4.x`

Here's a docker command to start a neo4j server:

```
docker run --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data --env=NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes --env=NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/test neo4j:3.4-enterprise
```

And here's a [github repository](https://github.com/flaviuratiu/spring-boot-neo4j-compatibility-test.git) with a simple test to reproduce the issue:

```
@SpringBootTest
class SpringBootNeo4jCompatibilityTestApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jClient neo4jClient;

    @Test
    void testNeo4jConnection_whenQueryIsRun_thenNoExceptionShouldBeThrown() {
        neo4jClient.query("MATCH (n) RETURN n")
                .run();
    }

}
```

The test fails when ran against `neo4j 3.4.x`, but it passes when ran against `neo4j 3.5.6-enterprise`.

Could you please suggest a way to make this connection work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j 3.4 is not maintained anymore, upgrade at least to 3.5: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/neo4j-supported-versions/